# Spark DataFrame to RDD - graph.apply with GraphX

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

I have a vertices and edges file in order to construct a graph using the `apply` method with `GraphX.`

My input files are in `json.gz` format and I am thus using the spark `sqlContext.read.json` function to import the data.

```
val vertices = sqlContext.read.json("vertices.json.gz")

res3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [index: bigint, point: array<double>, toid: string]
```

Using `vertices.show()` I can inspect the input.

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|index|               point|                toid|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    1|[508180.748, 1953...|osgb4000000031043205|
|    2|[508163.122, 1953...|osgb4000000031043206|
|    3|[508172.075, 1953...|osgb4000000031043207|
|    4|[508513.0, 196023.0]|osgb4000000031043208|
|    5|[514358.399, 1503...|osgb4000000029797733|
```

I have a `edges` file that I follow the same process with.

I now wish to construct a graph with `GraphX` using the [Graph.apply](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph$@apply[VD,ED](RDD[(VertexId,VD)],RDD[Edge[ED]],VD)(ClassTag[VD],ClassTag[ED]):Graph[VD,ED]) option. I know that this method does not accept `DataFrame` but rather `RDD` inputs.

In order to convert the files I have tried using the `.rdd` option resulting in:

```
val vert_rdd = vertices.rdd
vert_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[12] at rdd at <console>:36
```

However, this outputs a `.sql.Row` object rather than a standard `RDD` object. Thus, it is not accepted as an input when creating a Graph using `graph.apply`.

Is there a more direct method for using `JSON` files to GraphX or is there a different way to convert from a `DataFrame` to a `RDD`?

Edit.

Ultimately, the vertices file must be converted to a [VertexRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/graphx/VertexRDD.html) class. Where the index takes the place of `VertexId` and the `point` tuple and `toid` string are attributes.

The edge file must be converted to a [EdgeRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/graphx/EdgeRDD.html) class.

`Edges` file looks like this:

```
edges: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [index: bigint, length: double, nature: string, negativeNode: string, polyline: array<double>, positiveNode: string, term: string, toid: string]

+-----+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|index|            length|            nature|        negativeNode|            polyline|        positiveNode|                term|                toid|
+-----+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    1| 112.8275895775762|Single Carriageway|osgb4000000023183407|[492019.481, 1565...|osgb4000000023183409|Private Road - Re...|osgb4000000023296573|
|    2|141.57731318733806|Single Carriageway|osgb4000000023763485|[492144.493, 1567...|osgb4000000023183408|Private Road - Re...|osgb4000000023296574|
|    3|190.23352139011513|Single Carriageway|osgb4000000023183650|[492835.25, 15687...|osgb4000000023183652|Private Road - Re...|osgb4000000023296638|
```

Comment: What is the RDD expected format?

Comment: The `sqlContext.read.json` input creates `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`
Using `.rdd` we get `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`
I believe the expected format is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]`

Comment: I meant to ask about the format of each "line/row" of RDD (e.g. tuple of point,toid)

Comment: Thanks @Yaron. I've made some edits. Does this clarify?

Comment: `DataFrame.rdd` should return a RDD of type `Row`. So all you need to do is convert the `Row` objects to whatever type you need with a map, no? So in your case a function that maps `Row` to `Vertex`.

Comment: @LearningSlowly I tried to lead you to the direction LiMuBei wrote. i.e. using .rdd .map function to transform the Dataframe to the needed RDD format

Comment: Thanks Yaron and @LiMuBei for the pointers. I'll keep at it

Comment: @LearningSlowly Was this ever answered?

Comment: Unfortunately not @JoeS :(